# Can I use a TFS 2008 Build Server with .NET 4.0? With VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, tfsbuild

I am thinkin about building my first TFS 2008 Build Server. However, I would like to use it with VS 2010 solutions targeting both .NET 3.5 and 4.0. Will this work and what should I watch out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post to get some insights on setting this up...

http://blogs.msdn.com/willbar/archive/2009/11/01/building-net-4-0-applications-using-team-build-2008.aspx

Also, take a look at the following. My build failed due to the change in workspace name. I deleted the existing workspace names and had the build process recreate them correctly...

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/538958/deleteworkspacetask-fails-on-2008-build-machine-after-installing-visual-studio-2010-rc

Answer (score 0):

Will VS2010 test results get integrated back into TFS2008 for reporting, if this approach is followed?